# How to enable HTTPS of web console for an OKD Cluster hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, openshift, okd

I have followed the instructions from [here](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-default.html) to install an OKD cluster on AWS with my own domain. After installation succeed, I cannot access to the web console because of the self-signed SSL cert.

I have a wildcard SSL cert issued by AWS ACM, and I would like to apply it to the cluster. As the public ACM cert is not exportable, I have tried to attach the cert to the network load balancer, but still failed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot access to the web console because of the self-signed SSL cert

Are you sure? Most modern web browsers allow you to still bypass the TLS cert warning.

---

Anyway, so the web console is being exposed by the Ingress Controller, which means (unless you already customized the Ingress during installation) that this should be fronted by a CLB (classic load balancer) and not a NLB (network load balancer). The API is fronted by an NLB, and it's very likely that you'll still want a valid TLS certificate for the API.

But, since we're talking about the web console, we're talking about Ingress Controller configuration. Specifically, you should be looking at https://docs.okd.io/latest/networking/ingress-operator.html#nw-ingress-setting-a-custom-default-certificate_configuring-ingress

```bash
# Create the certificate secret
$ oc --namespace openshift-ingress create secret tls custom-certs-default \
     --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key

# Update the Ingress Controller to use the new certificate secret
$ oc patch --type=merge --namespace openshift-ingress-operator \
     ingresscontrollers/default \
     --patch '{"spec":{"defaultCertificate":{"name":"custom-certs-default"}}}'
```

The above instructions are for configuring the Ingress Controller post-install. This *should* also be doable pre-install, you would have to come up with some modified instructions similar to https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-network-customizations.html#nw-aws-nlb-new-cluster_installing-aws-network-customizations

Basically something like this *should* work (I haven't actually tried this)

```bash
# Use the installer to create a manifests directory
$ ./openshift-install create manifests --dir <installation_directory>

# Create your certificate secret in the manifests directory
$ oc --namespace openshift-ingress create secret tls custom-certs-default \
     --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key --dryrun -o yaml > \
     <installation_directory>/manifests/cluster-ingress-default-ingresscontroller-certificate.yaml

# Create the Ingress Controller manifest referencing the secret
$ touch <installation_directory>/manifests/cluster-ingress-default-ingresscontroller.yaml

# Populate the above YAML file with the Ingress Controller 
# manifest referencing the correct certificate secret
```